# How to use useGridApiContext outside of MUI datagrid

Tags: reactjs, material-ui, mui-x-data-grid

I wonder how can I use useGridApiContext outside of my datagrid in MUI.

I got a button that is used to expand all rows of a data tree, but I need it to be somewhere else than in any datagrid components.

How can I do that ?

Actually I use a custom toolbar, but I don't want to do this this way.

```
          <DataGridPro
            rows={works}
            columns={columns}
            treeData
            getTreeDataPath={(row) => row.hierarchy}
            groupingColDef={{
              headerName: "grtgx",
              resizable: true,
              flex: 1,
              renderCell: (props) => <CustomGroupingRow props={props} />,
            }}
            components={{
              Footer: CustomFooter,
              Toolbar: CustomToolbar,
            }}
         />
```

Comment: Take a look at [Data Grid - API object, Outside the Data Grid](https://mui.com/x/react-data-grid/api-object/#outside-the-data-grid)

Comment: Oh thank's a lot, couldn't find it in the documentation. It will do the tricks !